# Haproxy 1.6.2 not recognizing resolvers section

Tags: haproxy

As a test, I have a local bind instance running:

```
>netstat -ant | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.72.186.23:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
...

>nslookup mysubdomain.example.com 127.0.0.1
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Name:   mysubdomain.example.com
Address: nn.nn.nn.251
Name:   mysubdomain.example.com
Address: nn.nn.nn.249
Name:   mysubdomain.example.com
Address: nn.nn.nn.201
Name:   mysubdomain.example.com
Address: nn.nn.nn.138
```

I'm running haproxy 1.6.2 on the same host, with a resolvers section:

```
resolvers dns
    nameserver dns1 127.0.0.1:53
    nameserver dns2 10.72.186.23:53
    hold valid 10s
```

It doesn't reject the resolvers section, but doesn't seem to be using it, either. It doesn't show in the stats page, and attempting to add this service command:

```
server mysubdomain-dev mysubdomain.example.com
```

causes this error:

```
>service haproxy restart
 * Restarting haproxy haproxy
[ALERT] 322/171813 (10166) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:77] : 'server mysubdomain-dev' : invalid address: 'mysubdomain.example.com' in 'mysubdomain.example.com'
[ALERT] 322/165300 (29751) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 322/165300 (29751) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

The haproxy doc https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html indicates this should work.

server <name> <address>[:[port]] [param*]

...

<address> is the IPv4 or IPv6 address of the server. Alternatively, a
          resolvable hostname is supported, but this name will be resolved
          during start-up. Address "0.0.0.0" or "*" has a special meaning.

Is there some other piece that needs to be added to the haproxy.cfg that activates the resolvers section?

Comment: Unrelated to your question but a general hint: [Please do not use nslookup](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/nslookup-flaws.html). Use `dig` or `host` instead.

Comment: Old habits die hard. Working on it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When HAProxy first starts, it attempts to resolve the hostnames of any servers in all the backends to fill the server structures. During this first startup phase, HAProxy uses the OS resolver, i.e. generally the servers defined in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Only later, when the server's IP addresses are updated during checks, HAProxy uses its internal resolver configuration and its internal DNS resolver.

From your error description, it now seems as if your host itself can not resolve the `mysubdomain.example.com` hostname. HAProxy will only be able to start if it can resolve the hostnames without an explicit named nameserver. This can be verified with e.g.

```
dig mysubdomain.example.com
```

Comment: This particular host uses resolvconf, so changing /etc/network/interfaces to include the host effected the same result. Thanks!

Comment: What's the point of having the option for runtime resolvers configuration if you are forced to have resolvable hostnames at startup? Seems like a design oversight. Hopefully this gets fixed in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

might be you are not specifying the resolvers to use for that server

server mysubdomain-dev mysubdomain.example.com   ->

server mysubdomain-dev mysubdomain.example.com resolvers dns